# Don't understand why

Tags: mysql

I have this Stored Function that is supposed to return something from my database

```
CREATE DEFINER=`michele`@`%` FUNCTION `ProssimaDomanda`(`ParamIDQuestionario` INT(20), `ParamSessioneID` VARCHAR(20), `ParamUltimaDomanda` BIGINT(20)) RETURNS bigint(20) unsigned
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE Ritorno BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

    SET Ritorno=(SELECT NextIDDomanda 
        FROM Risposte
        INNER JOIN OpzioniDomande ON Risposte.IDRisposta = OpzioniDomande.IDRisposta
        WHERE 
            Risposte.SessioneID='ParamSessioneID'
                AND
            Risposte.IDQuestionario=ParamIDQuestionario
                AND
            Risposte.IDDomanda=ParamUltimaDomanda);

    /*IF (Ritorno IS NULL) 
        THEN SET Ritorno=(SELECT PrimaDomanda FROM PrimeDomande WHERE IDQuestionario=ParamIDQuestionario);
    END IF;*/


RETURN Ritorno;

END
```

But when I call it:

`SELECT ProssimaDomanda(1,1554891825,2);`

It returns Null.

Doing a normal select:

```
SELECT NextIDDomanda
        FROM Risposte
        INNER JOIN OpzioniDomande ON Risposte.IDRisposta = OpzioniDomande.IDRisposta
        WHERE 
            Risposte.SessioneID='1554891825'
                AND
            Risposte.IDQuestionario=1
                AND
            Risposte.IDDomanda=2;
```

Returns 3 which is correct.

Why does this happen?

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`michele`@`%` FUNCTION `ProssimaDomanda`(`ParamIDQuestionario` INT(20), `ParamSessioneID` VARCHAR(20), `ParamUltimaDomanda` BIGINT(20)) RETURNS bigint(20) unsigned
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE Ritorno BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    
    SET Ritorno=(SELECT NextIDDomanda 
  FROM Risposte
  INNER JOIN OpzioniDomande ON Risposte.IDRisposta = OpzioniDomande.IDRisposta
  WHERE 
   Risposte.SessioneID='ParamSessioneID'
    AND
   Risposte.IDQuestionario=ParamIDQuestionario
    AND
   Risposte.IDDomanda=ParamUltimaDomanda);
RETURN Ritorno;

END

Comment: Within your function, in the where-clause, you put `ParamSessioneID` within quotes being therefore interpreted as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Within your function, in the where-clause, you put `ParamSessioneID` within quotes being therefore interpreted as a literal string and not the parameter value.
Change your function into:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`michele`@`%` FUNCTION `ProssimaDomanda`
  (`ParamIDQuestionario` INT(20),
   `ParamSessioneID` VARCHAR(20),
   `ParamUltimaDomanda` BIGINT(20)
  )
RETURNS bigint(20) unsigned
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE Ritorno BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

    SET Ritorno=(SELECT NextIDDomanda 
        FROM Risposte
        INNER JOIN OpzioniDomande ON Risposte.IDRisposta = OpzioniDomande.IDRisposta
        WHERE 
            Risposte.SessioneID=ParamSessioneID -- This is where you have your problem!!!!
                AND
            Risposte.IDQuestionario=ParamIDQuestionario
                AND
            Risposte.IDDomanda=ParamUltimaDomanda);

    /*IF (Ritorno IS NULL) 
        THEN SET Ritorno=(SELECT PrimaDomanda FROM PrimeDomande WHERE IDQuestionario=ParamIDQuestionario);
    END IF;*/


RETURN Ritorno;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually  **INNER JOIN** clause matches rows in one table with rows in other tables and allows you to query rows that contain columns from both tables.

Comment: There INNER JOIN Return only one raw

Comment: Display row based on where condition in query so where condition satisfies only one row that's only you got one row.